# IP Address Info on Azure devops commits

Tags: azure-devops

is there a way to get the ip address from where the commits are done?I verified  get commit stats api call but does not have ip address info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IP Address Info on Azure devops commits

For this issue , I think it is impossible to get the IP address from where commits are done .

From the response body of [Commits - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api we can know that it does not contain IP address information. In addition,it is not safe to include IP address in the commit information. The main risk of using a public IP address: It allows anyone, anywhere to connect to your device directly from the Internet — and that includes cybercriminals. What’s more, attackers can change your Internet access settings, for example, forcing the router to feed you phishing websites where they can pinch your login credentials. For more dangers about public IP address,you can refer to this [blog](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/public-ip-dangers/24745/). Therefore, it is also not recommended to include the IP address of the machine where commits are done in the commit info.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination @Hugh Lin - MSFT